# Is it possible to use the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" property 3 times in a row?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, dataset

Is it possible to use the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" property 3 times in a row like binding a Combobox and a Datagrid to two tables of a dataset in a Master-Detail View. And then binding another Datagrid as a Master-Detail view to the first Detail (where the first Detail is the second Master)?
The tables of the dataset are all in a series connection.

For better understanding here's my code:

First Master-Detail:

`<ComboBox Name="ComboBoxLieferant" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="LFR_NAME"/>`

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FK_TBL_MATERIAL_TBL_LIEFERANTENSTAMM}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
```

The Combobox is bound to `this.DataContext = DSHistory.TBL_LIEFERANTENSTAMM;`
(the first table)

Second Master-Detail with the new Master as the first Detail:

`<DataGrid Name="dg2" "ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FK_TBL_MATERIAL_TBL_LIEFERANTENSTAMM/FK_TBL_BESTELLUNG_TBL_MATERIAL}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">`
The Path`FK_TBL_MATERIAL_TBL_LIEFERANTENSTAMM/FK_TBL_BESTELLUNG_TBL_MATERIAL` is the relationship between the first, the second and the third table

As you can see I'am using IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 3 times.

This is my Dataset: [image: the red lines are showing the described way]

But it doesn't work.
Is it possible that my binding is incorrect?
Thank's for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself.
I simply added another relations between these tables in the other direction.